# Программное изменение цвета CardView

Tags: java, android, cardview

Использую CardView в recycleView. По длинному нажатию включаю ActionMode и изменяю цвет cardView следующим образом:

```
((CardView)holder.itemView).setCardBackgroundColor()
```

Происходит следующая непонятная вещь. Фон меняется, но каким то образом остаётся ещё какой-то задний фон. Причём, если задаю значение фона из разметки всё нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CardView** пытается отрисовать тень.

Поставь **card_view:cardElevation="0dp"** - это должно решить проблему